# Django rest_framework permissions how to use in view that has object

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to build my own IP address blacklist blocker.

I found the[Django DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples) and associated SO questions and answers but struggling to implement this.

My IpTable model has ip_address field.

I modified the documentation example as follows:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlacklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blacklisted IPs.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blacklisted = IpTable.objects.filter(ip_address=ip_address).exists()
        return blacklisted  ## (if ip address in table returns True)
```

The question is: how is this being used by views where I want to block the user?

Is the idea to create a decoration that is before the view?

Or does a call to the global permission check go inside the view before rest of code?

In either of these options, what is syntax of the call to the global permissions check?

Also there has to be logic to do something eg redirect to a 403 page or custom page. Is it an if then statement in the view or perhaps in the global permission check function?

---

Edited to add:

The DRF documentation says

```
"Object level permissions are run by REST framework's generic views 
when **.get_object()** is called.  As with view level permissions, an 
exceptions.PermissionDenied exception will be raised if the user 
is not allowed to act on the given object." 

OR

"If you're writing your own views and want to enforce object level 
permissions, or if you override the get_object method on a generic 
view, then you'll need to explicitly call the 
**.check_object_permissions(request, obj)** method on the view at the 
point at which you've retrieved the object."

"These will either raise a PermissionDenied or NotAuthenticated exception
, or simply return if the view has the appropriate permissions."
```

Then this generic example is given:

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset())
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

Let's say I have a view as follows:

```
def country(request, country_id):
    country = Countries.objects.get(id=country_id)
```

What is the object referred to in the generic example? The thing I want to check is the request user's ip address.  That is being checked by the `has_permission` function in `BlacklistPermission` class.

What is syntax of expression that would send the request user to the `has_permission` function in `BlacklistPermission` class?

Would it be something like the following

```
def country(request, country_id):
    permission = request.user.check_object_permissions(request, request.user)
    if permission:
        country = Countries.objects.get(id=country_id)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Django as an IP address blocker? Really this is something that should be done at a much much lower level

Comment: For my needs Django will do fine, if I can get this particular solution working.